# Can't send mail from Outlook via C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm trying to send mails to my co workers, but after the 1st mail, the application crashes. I get this message

**COMException was unhandled by user code.** 
"The item has been moved or deleted."

```
private void SendMail()
{
    var usersEmailAddresses = Factory.Users.List(); // .List() lists all the data from the Users table.

    Application OutlookApplication = new Application();
    MailItem OutlookMail = (MailItem)OutlookApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

    OutlookMail.Subject = @"TEST/Ushqimi i caktuar per sot";

    MailBody //region, here I assign the MailBody Text.

    for (int index = 0; index < usersEmailAddresses.Count; index++)
    {
        OutlookMail.To = usersEmailAddresses[index].Email;  //Here is where I get the exception, AFTER trying to assign the second email.

        if (usersEmailAddresses[index].RecieveEmail && !usersEmailAddresses[index].IsOnVacation)
        {
            ((_MailItem)OutlookMail).Send();
        }
    }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm using System.Net.Mail. Also I forgot to mention, that the e-mail will be sent from the user who is logged in Outlook in the using PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MailItem OutlookMail = (MailItem)OutlookApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

You are creating the `mail item` outside of the loop.  It needs to be created inside the loop because once you send `OutlookMail` it fails to exist anymore so you need a new mail object.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error message “The item has been moved or deleted” is telling you the mail is already sent, so you should not change its "To" and send again.
Please try to create the MailItem inside for-loop, or add all the address into mail item before sending the mail.